# In a Symfony 4 application, how do I pass an environment variable to a service class?

Tags: php, symfony, docker, environment-variables

I am creating an app using Symfony 4 and Docker. In my .env file, I have the following line:

```
DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET=123456
```

... and in my services.yaml file, I have the following definition:

```
VMS\Application\DigitalRetail\Handler\DeviceForwardHandler:
    arguments:
        - env(DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET)
```

... which I expect to hand off my secret (123456) to my class, since I have this in that class:

```
public function __construct(string $deviceCreationSecret)
{
    $this->deviceCreationSecret = $deviceCreationSecret;
}
```

But when I run my app and dump out the value, I get `env(DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET)` rather then my secret (123456). What do I need to get access to that secret?

Comment: Try `'%env(DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET)%'`?

Comment: Cause `env(VARIABLE)` is used for __setting__ a variable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this way should work:

```
VMS\Application\DigitalRetail\Handler\DeviceForwardHandler:
    arguments:
        - '%env(DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET)%'
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/external_parameters.html

Answer (score 6):

Go to services.yml:

```
parameters:
    DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET: '%env(DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET)%'
```

After this, on the class, inject parameterBagInterface:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;

private $deviceCreationSecret;
private $params;

public function __construct(
    string $deviceCreationSecret,
    ParameterBagInterface $params
)
{
    $this->deviceCreationSecret = $deviceCreationSecret;
    $this->params = $params;
}
```

And then, for get parameter:

```
$this->params->get('DEVICE_CREATION_SECRET');
```